# React child not always rerendering after Apollo client useQuery completes

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am creating an app that uses React and GraphQL. Specifically Apollo client. When the app loads I am using the useQuery hook to make a query that gets the current user. It currently does this by sending a web token that is saved to localStorage. The user data returned from the query is passed as a prop to the navigation bar.

Only occasionally does the nav bar update when the user data is returned from the query. If I refresh the app 10 times, the nav bar may only rerender correctly 2-3 times.

Here is my code for the main app component that makes the query and passes the user data as a prop to the navigation bar.

```
const App = () => {
    
    if (!window.Promise) {
        window.Promise = PromisePolyfill
    }

    const [token, setToken] = useState(null)

    const currentUserQuery = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER, {
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            console.log("user query completed", data)
        }
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div id="page-container">
            {currentUserQuery.loading || currentUserQuery.error || currentUserQuery.data === null ? <NavBar currentUser={null} /> : <NavBar currentUser={currentUserQuery.data.me} />}
            <div id="content-wrap">
                <Link to="/users/63f6c389dadc96cc795852ab">test</Link>
                <div>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm setToken={setToken} />} />
                        <Route path="/signup" element={<h2>Sign Up</h2>} />
                        <Route path="/users/:id" element={<UserProfile />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={<h2>Page Not Found</h2>} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my code for the navigation bar that renders differently based on the currentUser prop.

```
const NavBar = ({currentUser}) => {

    console.log("current user prop in navbar", currentUser)


    if (currentUser) {
        return (
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect className="navbar" key={currentUser}>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="#" as="span">
                            <Link className='link' to="/"><img className="logo" src={ccLogo} alt="Chef's Club" /></Link>
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                                Another action
                            </NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                                Separated link
                            </NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect className="navbar" key={currentUser}>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="#" as="span">
                        <Link className='link' to="/"><img className="logo" src={ccLogo} alt="Chef's Club" /></Link>
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link href="#" as="span">
                        <Link className='link' to="/login">Login</Link>
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )

}
```

Again, the navigation bar rerenders sometimes, but not always, after the query returns. You can see from the console.log statement from onCompleted that the current user object is being returned from the server.

[Here is the console when the rerender occurs successfully. The app loads initially and the currentUser prop passed to the navigation bar is null. Then the query returns the user and finally the navigation bar rerenders correctly since the prop has changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeQib.png)

[Here is the console when the navigation bar does not rerender. You can see the user data is still returned from the server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp4fl.png)

Why does the navigation bar only sometimes update after the query is returned?

Answer (score -1):

What is the value of `currentUserQuery.error` when you experience the unexpected issue?

Comment: I just logged currentUserQuery.error when the App component renders. It is undefined whether the unexpected issue occurs or not.

Comment: Ok so my next question is around the `GET_CURRENT_USER` query and your auth token. How are you passing that token to the backend?

Comment: I used setContext to pass the token in the authorization header of requests sent from apollo client. Then the context function for Apollo server verifies the token sent with any request. I log the user object on the server before it is sent and in the client as seen in my screenshots above. Since the client is getting the proper user object I assume that is all set up properly. If it helps I can link the github repo so you can see all the code.

Comment: Sure, a repo link could help a lot

Comment: Here is the link to the project. I do appreciate you trying to help. https://github.com/Jacob-Elder/chefs-club

Comment: Hi @jelder96, I tried to run your app so I could reproduce the issue but I think there may be some setup steps that aren't documented.  I'd be happy to step through and offer some suggestions once I'm able to see what you see.